# sent mail from my mail in the app

Tags: ios, email

I  want to send mail in press button.

I want the user not show the sending mail.

I want the mail will send from my mail no from mail app in iPhone.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cant! Per Apple Requirements you cant send an email without the user knowing. If you really have a valid reason to do this, perhaps a call to a web server and have the server send the email out.

Comment: I need to do this because i want to send order to restaurant by email. The mail can sent from my mail.

Comment: Yes so that is fine. What you need to do is the server that is sending the restaurant the order should send the email. You could have the app make a web services call to do this. Apple has restrictions in place that wont allow your iPhone to do the actual sending.

Comment: How i do this? I only need send mail from my mail with text.

Comment: Are you not using any kind of web server?